# Retrieving firebase topics data for app instance - 401 error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to retrieve a list of subscribed FCM topics for an app instance.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#get_information_about_app_instances) states that I should make a GET request at `https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/<IID_TOKEN>?details=true`, passing in `Authorization:key=<WEB_API_KEY>` as a header.

Here's how the request looks inside my client:

```
const getTopics = (token) => {
    fetch('https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/${token}?details=true', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'key=AIzaSy...dQ80g'
        }
    })
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

const messaging = firebase.messaging()

messaging
    .requestPermission()
    .then(() => messaging.getToken())
    .then(getTopics)
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

And this is the response I'm getting:
[image: response]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Clearly one of my tokens is invalid, but according the documentation this should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone finds this question and needs an answer, I found the issue: the documentation is wrong, the Authorization header requires the cloud messaging project SERVER KEY. This is NOT the same as the general API key.

Here's where you can find the correct key as of Oct 2019:
[image]

Google, please keep your documentation up to date, I wasted hours trying to figure this out!